# How to Import This ManyToManyField from JSON?

Tags: django, json, manytomanyfield

The JSON file is structured like this:

```
"quarterstaff": {
            "id": 10,
            "img": "quarterstaff_lg.png",
            "dname": "Quarterstaff",
            "components": null,
            "created": false
        },

"oblivion_staff": {
            "id": 67,
            "img": "oblivion_staff_lg.png",
            "dname": "Oblivion Staff",
            "components": [
                "quarterstaff",
                "sobi_mask",
                "robe"
            ],
            "created": true
        },
```

I'm having trouble importing the components values. The "components" values are the key names of other items, that are used in a recipe to create a new item. These are my models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    itemkey = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=255)        
    components = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, through='Composition')

class Composition(models.Model):
    whole = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name = 'as_a_whole')
    component = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name = 'as_a_part')
```

And I use a command file to import the data from the JSON file.

```
def update_item(self, key, item):
        try:
            db_item = Item.objects.get(unique_id=item['id'])
            print 'Updating %s..' % item['dname']
        except Item.DoesNotExist:
            print 'Creating %s..' % item['dname']
            db_item = Item()
            db_item.unique_id = item['id']
        db_item.itemkey = key
        db_item.dname = item['dname']
        db_item.img = item['img']
        db_item.components = item['components']
        db_item.save()

def fetch_items(self, result):
        try:
            for key, item in result['itemdata'].items():
                self.update_item(key, item)
```

I was getting this error: `AttributeError: Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use items.Composition's Manager instead.` I believe it's because of the `db_item.save()` since I'm using a through option on the ManyToManyField, for which you apparently can't use add, create or assignment to create relationships.

So what should I be doing to get the components values into the database? I apologize if this question is too broad? I really don't know what I'm doing! I'm completely new to programming, Python is my first language.

Also, when I look at the items.item schema in the database, there is no table for 'components.' Why is that? Are ManyToManyFields placed in separate tables or something?

Answer (score 0):

To add to a items many-to-many you use

`components.add(item)`

i.e

```
for component in items["components"]:
    db_item.components.add(component)
```

Many to many relations uses a so called lookup table, 
you have defined such a table via the `through="Composition"` parameter.
This means the Composision model will be used as the special table to store those relations.

if you dont specify a through table django will create one automatically to be used transparently.